# retaining the same value on form submission in a drop down list Using spring's <spring:bind> tag

Tags: jsp, spring-mvc

i have a drop-down list in my jsp and using spring mvc,the problem i am facing is, on form submission the value in the drop-down gets change to the default value.

i have binded this drop-down list as Shown below--

backingObject contains List of ObjectA and ObjectA contains another Object ObjectB,
ObjectB contains primitive type property id

```
<spring:bind path="backingObject.listOfA[0].ObjectB.id">
    <form:select path="listOfA[0].ObjectB.id" id="uioption" class="dropdown_background">
        <c:forEach var="Option" items="${Options}">
            <c:choose>
                <c:when test="${status.value eq Option.id}">
                    <option selected="selected" value="${Option.id}" name="${Option.name }" age="${Option.age }">
                        <c:out value="${Option.name}"/>
                    </option>
                </c:when>
                <c:otherwise>
                    <option value="${Option.id}" name="${Option.name}"  age="${Option.age }">
                        <c:out value="${Option.name}"/>
                    </option>
                </c:otherwise>
            </c:choose>
        </c:forEach>
    </form:select>
</spring:bind>
```

i am using ajax to send post request to controller.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know if this is a particularly good fix, but couldn't you set the dropdown value back within the ajax method?

```
function submitForm(itemSelected){   
   //submit form values

   //reset dropdown selected item to item passed into method
   $('#DropDownBoxID').val(itemSelected);
}
```

Comment: thanks for replying,your fix too can work but i have got the solution,actually its the code's mischeif, the backing object was somehow getting reset in the controller therefore all the binded values were replaced,else the above code works fine,but now instead of binding objectB id i have binded list of ObjectA,and used the spring initBinder and used PropertyEditorSupport class to fill the list(objectA) with ObjectB,where objectB is newly created object in class extending PropertyEditorSupport and value obtained from form is set into it's(ObjectB) id field.

Comment: Lol sounds complicated but as long as you have found your solution! Feel free to up-vote my answer if you think it helped =P